# Physical Inventory records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inventory-management

I am trying to build a simple inventory system.
I am collecting data from users through a form
Here is my forms controller:

```
class FormsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_form, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  #belongs_to :powders

  # GET /forms
  # GET /forms.json
  def index
    @forms = Form.all
  end

  # GET /forms/1
  # GET /forms/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /forms/new
  def new
    @form = Form.new
  end

  # GET /forms/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /forms
  # POST /forms.json
  def create
    @form = Form.new(form_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @form.save
        format.html { redirect_to @form, notice: 'Form was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @form }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @form.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /forms/1
  # PATCH/PUT /forms/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @form.update(form_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @form, notice: 'Form was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @form }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @form.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /forms/1
  # DELETE /forms/1.json
  def destroy
    @form.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to forms_url, notice: 'Form was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_form
       @form = Form.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def form_params
      params.require(:form).permit(:date, :shift, :batch, :silicate, :fw)
    end
end
```

The report will show the data collected through the forms:

```
 Date   Shift   Batch   Silicate        Fw  
2015-01-19  day     1       4000        450         
2015-01-19  Night   2       7000        600 
2015-01-21  day     8       4500        340
```

now I need an another report Say FW Inventory reports.Table structure of this report should be :

```
Date, Opening Stock, Receipts, Consumptions and Closing Stock
```

Here the FW Inventory report which should capture the Date and Consumption details from the forms reports. It should capture Date-wise total figure and not the shift wise figure of consumption.

Now, I created a Firewood Controller (App/Controllers/firewoods_controller.rb) which is :

```
class FirewoodsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_firewood, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 # has_many :forms
 # belongs_to :forms


  # GET /firewood
  # GET /firewood.json
  def index
  #  @Firewoods = Firewood.all ( I want to show the inventory reports for Firewood  )
  end

  # GET /firewoods/1
  # GET /firewoods/1.json
  def show

  end

  # GET /firewdoods/new
  #def new
   # @firewdood = Firewdood.new
 # end

  # GET /firewdoods/1/edit
 # def edit
#  end

  # POST /firewdoods
  # POST /firewdoods.json



  # PATCH/PUT /firewdoods/1
  # PATCH/PUT /firewdoods/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @firewdood.update(firewdood_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @firewdood, notice: 'Firewdood was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @firewdood }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @firewdood.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /firewdoods/1
  # DELETE /firewdoods/1.json
  def destroy
    @firewdood.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to firewdoods_url, notice: 'Firewdood was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_firewdood
      @firewdood = Firewdood.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def firewdood_params
      params.require(:firewdood).permit(:date, :opening, :stock, :receipt, :issues, :closing, :stock)
    end
end
```

and here is the firwood index page(App/views/firewoods/index.html.erb
 where i Need the inventory reports :

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Opening</th>
      <th>Stock</th>
      <th>Receipt</th>
      <th>Issues</th>
      <th>Closing</th>
      <th>Stock</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <div class ="report" </div>
      <table>


      <tr>
        <td><%= form.date %></td>
        <td><%= form.fw %></td>

        <td><%= link_to 'Show', form %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_form_path(firewdood) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', form, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and the model at (app/models/firewoods.rb):

```
class Firewood < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Now I want to show data as per below formate: The output should be displayed though App/views/firewoods/index.html.erb (localhost:3000/firewoods/) I know the routing.Opening Stock I will put manually. Receipt figure let's ignore at the moment. I need the consumption figures to be captured from the FormsController/table and closing stock equation should be op.stock + receipt - Consumption.

```
Date, Opening Stock, Receipts, Consumptions and Closing Stock
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the question here ?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I want to create an another report namely "Firewood Inventory Reports" which should show me Date-wise consumption of firewood Table format for the FW Inventory reports I have posted above

Comment: Are you asking how you'd fit the second report into this controller? In that case, you have two separate "things" that are trying to share the same controller, which is usually a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you so much Justin. No I am not trying two separate things in same controller. I want a 3rd new controller. I will provide you more details in this regard